# WiX: Handling an alert during installation

Tags: wix, continuous-deployment

I want to create a WiX package for a task scheduler. I am able to create the task while I install the package and during the uninstall from control panel am able to remove it successfully. But, when I try to install the upgraded version It gives an alert saying:

WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "taskNew" (Y/N)?

Here am using the below Major upgrade statement for upgrading the msi, where the previous version will be first un installed and then the updated version will be installed.

I want this package to be installed in nightly build as per Continuous deployment. As there should not be any manual intervention, I want this to be Y for all the times. Can anyone please help on this

The commands am using for installing  task scheduler:

```
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduleTask"
              Return="check"
              Execute="deferred"
              Impersonate="no"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              ExeCommand="&quot; [SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /CREATE /TN &quot;taskNew&quot; /TR &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]installerAbc.exe&quot; /SC DAILY /ST 12:30" />
```

Command used for un-installing task :

```
<CustomAction Id="RemoveScheduleTask"
              Return="ignore"
              Execute="deferred"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate="no"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /DELETE /TN &quot;taskNew&quot;" />
```

Comment: When you say that you Reinstall the upgraded version, do you use the exact same msi package used for the initial upgrade ie. same product code, package code and upgrade code. I am guessing you do. Could you please confirm? Also, whats your purpose here that requires you to re-install? why cant you just uninstall and re-install?  Also, between each subsequent builds, what do you change such as the ProductCode, PackageCode etc

Comment: Hi Kiran.. Small correction here, Its not a re install. I am installing the updated version. In this instance am not changing the package code,product code. Am just updating the version to higher value. As part of the Cont Deployment we will be installing the updated version. For this.. I am using Major upgrade tag as below.. <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of Product is already installed." Schedule="afterInstallValidate"/> which uninstall the previous version and install the new one.During un install I got the alert where I need to click Y in runtime only

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by updating the command itself.. By adding /f flag as below makes it to delete the task forcefully.

ExeCommand = ""[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE" /DELETE /TN "taskNew&quot **/f;**"